# Have any non-German NATO forces been stationed in Eastern Germany since reunification?

Tags: germany, nato

What, if any, non-German NATO forces have been stationed in Eastern Germany (i.e. the former GDR territory) since reunification?

Comment: All questions should document [preliminary research](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786).  Even if it is just a list of google searches; that significantly helps us to start research and prevents us from repeating efforts that you've already made.

Comment: @MCW I'm  not sure what I can do other than googling.

Comment: @Acccumulation you could link the video from your Skeptics.SE question.

Comment: @DanilaSmirnov Indeed, it seems crucial to understand that this Q is based _on QOP's inferences_ displayed [here](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/53094/chomskys-nato-russia-ukraine-claims). These should be repeated here, or as mentioned at least show more prior research than the evident 'watched a video, had questions understanding it'. Otherwise, the answer(s) given here end up _quite oblique_ (à la X/Y-problem) to the underlying target of this inquiry. The A below could be read as to not disprove the video's statement, but it might be read as an overly specific dementi?

Comment: Not sure we want to re-open this question unless the issues raised in comments are addressed.  The current draft of the question obscures that it is based on the notions of a _highly_ political and contentious author, which is very relevant to any research.  I normally support re-opening questions with a highly voted answer, but I think the question needs to be clarified that it is inherently political.

Comment: The assumption inferred from Chomsky's claim is wrong: _he means German NATO forces_ (alternative would have been DMZ for the ex-GDR). But apart from that, training of foreign troops in the German East is continuous, if somewhat transitory in their respective nature, eg in officers' schools _all the time,_ and for exercises JAWTEX14 national forces from US, NL, F, I, Sl, Gr, TR, HU, even Aut, Fi and CH(!), likewise for DEFENDER20/21. Stationing of non-German troops on permanent bases however remained exclusive to the West.

Answer (score 15):

No, the **stationing** (or **deployment**) of foreign armed forces and nuclear weapons in the territory of the former German Democratic Republic is explicitly forbidden in the last sentence of Article 5 (3) of the **two plus four treaty** of 1990-09-12.

This came into effect after the 1994-08-31, which marked the end of the Soviet military presence on German soil. Until then Article 5 (1,2) was in effect that allowed the continued stationing of the Western Allies in Berlin.

Allthough occasionally exercises in (and transit through) the territory of the former German Democratic Republic do take place, there are no (non-German) NATO troops stationed there.

---

> [Treaty on the Final Settlement with Respect to Germany (two plus four)](https://usa.usembassy.de/etexts/2plusfour8994e.htm)
> **Article 5 (3)**
> *Following the completion of the withdrawal of the Soviet armed forces* from the territory of the present German Democratic Republic and of Berlin, units of German armed forces assigned to military alliance structures in the same way as those in the rest of German territory may also be stationed in that part of Germany, but without nuclear weapon carriers. This does not apply to conventional weapon systems which may have other capabilities in addition to conventional ones but which in that part of Germany are equipped for a conventional role and designated only for such. **Foreign armed forces and nuclear weapons or their carriers will not be *stationed* in that part of Germany or *deployed* there**.

Oxford Learner's Dictionaries:

- [stationed](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/station_2?q=stationed):

  - *especially from one of the armed forces, to work in a place for a period of time*
- [deployed](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/deploy?q=deployed):

  - *to move soldiers or weapons into a position where they are ready for military action*

---

**Sources**:

- [Treaty on the Final Settlement with Respect to Germany - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treaty_on_the_Final_Settlement_with_Respect_to_Germany)
- [Vertrag vom 12. September 1990 über die abschließende Regelung in Bezug auf Deutschland (Zwei-plus-Vier-Vertrag) - Auswärtiges Amt](https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/de/aussenpolitik/themen/internationales-recht/-/240218)

  - copy of original treaty, as PDF, in the 4 languages can be downloaded
- [German-American Relations - Treaty on the Final Settlement with Respect to Germany (two plus four)](https://usa.usembassy.de/etexts/2plusfour8994e.htm)

Comment: Thats the legal situation -- whats the actual situation? Is the treaty honored?

Comment: @Polygnome Why wouldn't it be? Stationing troops usually requires military bases, so it is not a short term thing. There are multiple bases in West Germany with non-German NATO troops, so there is no real reason to break the treaty.

Comment: @quarague because troops are stationed further east, and generally this kind of treaty is one that isn't known for being honored

Comment: @quarague There is no reason to just assume a treaty is honored. I'm pretty sure this one is honored, but it would be nice if you added some sources that actually say that yes, this treaty *is* honored. Otherwise you only describe how the situation *should* be, not what the situation actually *is*.

Comment: There's no reason to just assume a treaty *isn't* honoured either. Or more to the point, treaty violations habitually draw diplomatic protests. Are there anyone complaining about this one not being followed?

Comment: @Polygnome The third paragraph describes the actual situation. If it was not the case, be rest assured, that Russia would have complained about a treaty violation. They have not. Viktor Baranez, a former Russian Defense Ministry spokesman, claims that NATO 'has broken all the promises it made during the process of German reunification'. But the treaty itself makes no mention of eastern Europe, only restrictions inside Germany. In 1990, a NATO expansion was not a topic since the Warsaw Pact still existed.

Comment: @Polygnome It is difficult, if not impossible, to supply a source for something that doesn't exist. What you can read in the local German press are **traffic warnings**, about once a year, caused by the transit (or exercises) of troops.

Comment: @MarkJohnson The paragraph offers no source.

Comment: You may want to include this visualisation: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ausländische_Militärbasen_in_Deutschland or the entire list. There are of course foreign uniforms present regularly in eg Dresden OSH officer's school, and the likes of such, or eg planes using the airfields etc. So it's perhaps 'not honoured' in the sense of 'no foreign uniform ever on that soil'. Small scale & nitpicky. Unlike even further east, outside Germany again, there are indeed no official permanent camp-like or other large scale structures in the East of Germany?

Comment: @LаngLаngС I see no need to do so, since the text of the treaty speaks for itsself, just as the terms **stationed** and **deployed** do not include 'foreign uniforms present regularly in eg Dresden OSH officer's school' and 'planes using the airfields etc.'.

Comment: The important thing I suggested is the Wp link. For the definition of "stationed", which is admittedly nitpicky (for very small numbers compared to 'an actual dedicated base'), we should highlight that a treaty text is 'the theory', the reality, well 'is itself'… & also speaks for itself; that 'no-troops' is commonly understood differently (they _do use_ the local infrastructure, German based, while in the West things also got "more integrated"), & that even the mil-lingo in actual use speaks eg of troops _"stationed at the school"_ or "deployed" eg in DEFENDER20 ("Brandenburg wird NATO-Camp")

Comment: @LаngLаngС Again, I see no need. When required, anybody can look the terms up in a standard dictionary: [stationed](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/station_2?q=stationed): *especially from one of the armed forces, to work in a place for a period of time* ; [deployed](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/deploy?q=deployed): *to move soldiers or weapons into a position where they are ready for military action*

Comment: You argue that "it's prohibited, ergo not happening" (try that with proving murder doesn't exist), and that's theoretical. I've shown you practical examples in which this treaty's stipulations were _not_ upheld. 20000 US troops deployed, _in_ military action, towards the east for one. The 'deployment' angle of the treaty is therefore clearly just toast? So it's not very convincing to only argue from that legalistic idealism perspective. There are no permanent 'foreign' bases in the east, true. But the rest needs less dictionary quotes, more nuance from reality.

Comment: @LаngLаngС Then you should have supplied your own answer before voting to close this question. But as stated elsewhere, Russia has never charged Germany in violating Article 5 (3) of the **two plus four treaty**. That in itsself should tell you everything.